# How to create a single jar with different main classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have 2 main classes in the project and i want to merge them into a single jar. because i want to use this jar in another project. so can you please suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You would go about this the same you would creating a JAR file from 2 classes which both do *not* have a `main` method:

```
jar -cvf your_jar.jar MainClass1.java MainClass2.java
```

If you want to choose one of the `main` methods to be the one which will execute by default when the JAR is run, then you can create a manifest file with the following contents:

```
Main-Class: MainClass1 (Manifest.txt)
```

Then you can run the `jar` tool like this:

```
jar -cvfm jarfile.jar Manifest.txt MainClass1.java MainClass2.java
```

Comment: I want to do it in eclipse can you please let me know how we can do it in eclipse?

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm ... you should have tagged your question with "Eclipse"